# redirect_uri and how to host callback.html on SoundCloud?

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to access Soundcloud from a local HTML page on my laptop. I am stuck at the part of hosting "callback.html" as a redirect_uri. The script I am trying to run is the basic Authenication JavaScript from the Soundcloud documentation page:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize client with app credentials
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'my_client_id',
  redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1/Users/Maria/Documents/SoundcloudClient/callback.html'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
  });
});
</script>
```

This script gets me to the connect pop-up when I launch the page in Chrome and Firefox. 
But, once I have logged in as a Soundcloud user, I get the following error:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1
```

If I change my redirect_uri to localhost I get the same error.

If I try:

```
files:///C:/Users/Maria/Documents/SoundcloudThinClient/callback.html
```

I get a similar error.

I also tried:

```
ocalhost:3000
```

and:

```
localhost:8080
```

even though I'm not sure what would be listening on those ports.

So, basically, I'm asking what path do I put for callback.html in order for this to work?

I confess I don't know how the redirct_uri actually functions. I looked at the Oauth pages for it, but I don't understand them. I am beginning to think that I can't simply create an HTML page, paste the JavaScript, create a callback.html file and have this work, even though the SC documentation seems to say that this is possible. If so, what steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am beginning to attempt this. I believe you have to go to the developer site and sign up as having an app. The redirect uri is asked for and the form gives you an API key you can use in your app.

I'm using drupal so, perhaps adding the oath module and using Php to add the api key might work well.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think I solved it.

Morning-after-edit: I posted this dead-tired after working towards a solution through the night. Now, the day after, I realize that you were speaking about the general problem, whereof I face a very particular instance. The following only applies directly to registering soundcloudlabs' *soundcloud-group-recorder*: https://github.com/soundcloudlabs/soundcloud-group-recorder. There is probably a more general principle lurking behind there, though:

First: yes, you do have to register the app as your own at Soundcloud. At least I presumed so. And doing that, you must register correctly where on your server you will place the callback.html file. Take the *ClientID* assigned to your app and use that in the API intialize procedure.

Now, I'm a novice and know very little coding. But I started looking around in the main file, application.js.

1. At the top of the file there are two instances of *client_id* and *redirect_uri* each. I'm not sure if that serves a purpose or if one is technically superfluous. Through trial and error I found out that replacing the second instance of each with my own data worked.
2. Then there is *groupId* and *groupUrl*, both of which should contain your info, within quotation marks.
3. After a lot of trial and error, still having trouble getting the thing to run, I looked around and saw that, whereas early in the file, *client_id* was hooked within SC.initialize, *redirect_uri* was not. Under the line:

`client_id: CLIENT_ID`

I added:

`redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI`

– with a customary comma in between. And that's it. It runs.