# how to authenticate Soundcloud API with redirect_uri (callback.html)

Tags: api, authentication, soundcloud

The final goal is to let users be able to upload / download files through the soundcloud API.

I have registered my app, but now I have got problems with the authentication. In the app registration i must define a redirect URI for authentication, their default is callback.html. What to put there myself?

I dont know what to put there, in redirect uri of the app or in the code (assuming it must be the same) I've tried making a callback.html myself, but it doesnt work. 
I'm starting to think it must be an online link. But i'm only working on localhost..

I've found a very similar question here:
[redirect_uri and how to host callback.html on SoundCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334361/redirect-uri-and-how-to-host-callback-html-on-soundcloud)

but it doesnt solve my problem.

I realize this is very basic stuff, but i hope i can get some clear help.
thank you very much

EDIT : for testing, i've put http://www.samplewars.com/ in the app registration redirect_uri and in the redirect_uri in my code, and now i get the pop-up asking for acces to the soundcloud account, after clicking connect it goes to samplewars.com. How do i make it go to the same page, (localhost url). Is actually possible to put an offline link there, as i'm only working on localhost? i dont have anything online.

Answer (score 3):

The callback file is used to send the authentication token back to your application. In your case it should be something like `http://www.samplewars.com/soundcloud-callback.html`. For development, you could register a different application which points to your local setup (eg `http://localhost/soundcloud-callback.html` or whatever).

If you use the SoundCloud Javascript API, this is fairly simple. There's an example page in [the documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript).

Answer (score 1):

in your `windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` file

add line`127.0.0.1 localhost.samplewars.com` 
and you can use that domain for testing purposes.

Comment: If you are on Mac follow this instructions: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/