# Register with SoundCloud using localhost

Tags: api, proxy, mamp, soundcloud

I want to register an application with SoundCloud.

I don't have a valid URL for my app according to SoundCloud as I am trying to register it with `http://localhost:8888/pathtofile`.

Is there any way to register with SoundCloud using MAMP local server?

Answer (score 1):

Are you Mac, Windows or Linux?

If Mac, follow the instructions in this StackOverflow comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636333/42776

I'll repeat them here...

> in your windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file
>
> Add line `127.0.0.1 localhost.samplewars.com` and you can use that
>   domain for testing purposes.